# Declaring an array type

Tags: c#, arrays

While discussing another question on SO, I was told that the syntax

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
```

Is better than

```
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
```

My question is, when is the first syntax useful and when is the second syntax useful? And why?

Comment: They do completely different things.

Comment: When you know the type at compile time, I can't see *any* benefit to using the second form.

Comment: Unlike most classes, Array provides the CreateInstance method, instead of public constructors, to allow for **late bound access**. - [Array.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx)

Comment: @asawyer how do they do different things? They produce the exact effect, except for the return type may be..

Comment: @nawfal Seems to me that a different return type would qualify something as different.

Comment: @asawyer but are they really different? Run a GetType() on both of them and they are just the same. Its only a question how it is *typed*. And its only a matter of casting to its original type. Even if still they are different, they **are not completely different**. Is `Cat` **completely** different from `Cat` in the guise of `Mammal`?

Comment: @nawfal For compile time static analysis, yes it they are different.

Comment: @asawyer honestly my first comment was regarding the "completely" part, which makes OP's question look like silly. Nevertheless you chipped in with your appropriate justification ;) If you comment the same under questions like *when to use `IList` over `List`* etc I wont complain :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This creates a strongly typed monodimensional array "directly":

```
int[] array = new int[10];
```

Under the hood it uses the IL command `newarr`.

This one is more similar to using reflection to create an array (the type can be decided at runtime)

```
int[] array2 = (int[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
```

The array created in the end is the same but the speed of creating it is much slower when using `Array.CreateInstance`. Note that with `Array.CreateInstance` you can dynamically select the type of the array (in the same way that through reflection you can create an instance of a type given the type at runtime), for example:

```
Type type = someCondition ? typeof(int) : typeof(string);
Array array2 = Array.CreateInstance(type, 10);
```

Another big difference: the "base" `Array` class is weakly typed (so its methods use `object` parameters, instead of `int`/`string`'/`something`). So:

```
int num = (int)array2.GetValue(1); // You have to cast the return value to int from object
```

---

Another reason to use

```
array[5] = 1;
```

instead of

```
array2.SetValue(5, 1);
```

is that the first method is optimized in the IL code as a direct access to a monodimensional array (`stelem` and `ldelem`). The same is true for `GetValue`.

---

The reason I'm using the term "monodimensional array":

In .NET there are two "types" of arrays: the monodimensional arrays and the "complex" arrays (they can be multidimensional, or with the first element not at the 0 index, or both). The second group is much slower. The `stelem` and `ldelem` work only with monodimensional arrays. For multidimensional/special arrays "hidden" methods are used to access them (the C# compiler changes the get and set so that these methods are called) (they are similar to the `GetValue`/`SetValue` of the `Array` class, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/597729/613130 )

Comment: Thanks, this answers my query and also gives insight into IL code. This was exactly what I was looking for. Accepted!

Answer (score 5):

On compile time, looks like there is no big difference between them. Just like arrays, **[Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx)** method also make reference-type elements are initialized to `null`. value-type elements are initialized to `zero`.

[image]

Only difference for the second one is; from *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx)*;

> Unlike most classes, Array provides the CreateInstance method, instead
>   of public constructors, to allow for late bound access.

Also as Stefano Altieri [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14980612/447156), first syntax requires array size in *compile time*, but the second one need the size in *run-time*. For example, you can build these codes successfully;

```
int[] numbers1 = new int[10];
Array numbers2 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), -1);
```

But you can't build these;

```
int[] numbers1 = new int[];
Array numbers2 = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), -1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say that there is "No difference" between an an expression that returns `int[10]` and an expression that returns `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the visual. It is helpful. If you do check the "Type" column, you will see that the two declarations are indeed different.

Answer (score 4):

The samples you wrote are equivalent. The point is that to use the first syntax (new int[size]) you need to know the array type at compile time.

The second syntax allow you to decide at runtime the type of the array items. This is far more powerful, but you just don't need this power always. I.e.

```
Type myType = SelectTheBestType();
var numbers = Array.CreateInstance(myType, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul)'s answer is pretty good. A simple reason of your question is

***If an array is passed as object or interface, the element type is unknown at compile time.***

[[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088636/can-the-element-type-be-defined-with-an-unknown-class-possibly-presents-as-arra/14088788#14088788)] might bring you the idea, and [[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533082/why-doesnt-array-class-expose-its-indexer-directly/14735142#14735142)] is some code for example.

> when is the first syntax useful and when is the second syntax useful?

The method in the link of example,

```
static IList CreateArray<T>(this T source);
```

the generic type parameter is `T` rather than `T[]` because of I cannot suppose that `source` **necessarily** been an array, but it still **possibly**. Thus I can only use `Array.CreateInstance` inside the method.

Most of time, if the element type is already known at compile time, it's better to use the syntax provided by the language.